# Number of opengl contexts in android

Tags: android, eclipse

I used opengl tracer in eclipse for the first time for my android app and I noticed that there are two contexts to choose from in the generated trace file. Context 0 and Context 1. Is this normal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is normal. I use the OpenGL tracer pretty often and for all my apps there are two Gl Context's. The other context is from the system UI or default android views that use some sort of openGL.

Any way the context you want to look at is context 0.

Comment: I have always seen it the other way. Context 0 being the composition stuff that shows up for the first few frames, and context 1 the actual rendering from the app.

Comment: Interesting, I think this has something to do with the order views are inflated, if the custom SurfaceView is inflated later than the Android default views etc. it will have context 1. At least that's what I think.